# Arsenic-Based Life

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337). Title based on [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/829/).</sup>

---

Find the lead actor.[image: credits]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cute flavor quirk that phenomist may have missed (or at least didn't mention in [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66803/arsenic-based-life/66804#66804)) is the

> common accreditation of actors in credits as "X as Y" (e.g. "Emma Stone as Mia Dolan"); hence "GR as SHOPPER", etc.

With that in mind, and based on [Phylyp's comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66803/arsenic-based-life#comment201488_66804), the solution seems to just be

> NITROGEN AS OLD ARGON = N AS A = NASA
>  (which can be seen as the lead actor in the sense of "a participant in an action or process"; in 2010, NASA research fellow Felisa Wolfe-Simon isolated GFAJ-1, a microbe that was supposedly capable of substituting arsenic for a small percentage of its phosphorus to sustain its growth.)

Comment: Congratulations on a very well-written first answer! Thanks to phenomist, Phylyp and Riley for their contributions, too.

Answer (score 14):

## Partial answer

> Based on the title of the puzzle, perhaps we should find animals (and other things) that contain an As (for arsenic):
>  [image]
>  We manage to find: grASshopper, jASmine, mAStiff, parASite, pegASus, pheASant, wASp, weASel, yeASt. Next, look at the letters that each line goes through in order of the left side. You get the cluephrase **NITROGEN AS OLD ARGON**, which seems like a pretty good cluephrase about a puzzle about elements, but not sure where to go from here. (There's a film called "Arsenic and Old Lace" who is starred by Cary Grant, but that connection is tenuous at best.)

Comment: ROT13(Hagvy 1957 netba'f flzoby jnf 'N'. Znlor n fhofgvghgvba bs bar sbe gur bgure, juvpu vf EBG-guvegrra?)

Comment: So then (Wbua Tyraa)?

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer** based on @phenomist's answer.

From the cluephrase of

> Nitrogen as old argon

We do the following:

> Convert to chemical symbols:

.

> N As ? Ar ("as" was already the chemical symbol for Arsenic)

And because

> Carbon is old (now it's arsenic based life) we replace "old" with "C".

So we get

> Nascar

At first I thought this was the final answer, but now I see it doesn't really fit with the movie theme, and isn't an actor. The search continues.

Comment: Maybe [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66803/arsenic-based-life#comment201488_66804)...?